# Is there a function to have Java pick an item from a list and remove it?

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

I've created a list of 8 items, and I want Java to pick one at (psuedo)random and then remove it from the list. After that, I want it to repeat the process until it gets down to one item.

Here's the code

```
package randomlist;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
    
public class output {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i <1 ; i++) {
        Random generate = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        String[] color = {"Black", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Mint", "Rose", "Purple" };
        String colorsprint = colors[generate.nextInt(colors.length)];
        
        System.out.println(colorsprint);}}}
```

Currently, it outputs its choice as expected. What I want it to do is to output its choice and then move on to another list with the 7 remaining items, but I don't want to have to manually code 256 different lists to nest it with "if *a* then pick from *b*, etc.

So far, all the code I've tried has resulted in a compiler error or the program simply not running. I've even gotten it to work as a nested list, outputting from another list based on its first choice, but that's not working here.

I'm sure it's something I've already tried and just messed up, but I've run out of my own knowledge.

EDIT: I guess I should clarify; I know how to solve the issue, I just am hoping there's a more efficient way than doing it all manually with CTRL-C/CTRL-V; it'll make for extremely unwieldy code if I have to make 256 lists for the permutations of 8.

Comment: [List.remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) with a Math.random() times the list size tends to get the job done just fine, so it usually doesn't have its own implementation, unless you're writing a data structure that extends List.

Comment: I suggest you use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/List.html) instead of an array. `List` has a [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) method, which does most of the work - it even returns the item previously in that position.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can you please elaborate on that? It sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: There's... not much to elaborate on? Literally just remov an element at index (size * random) to pop a random element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of implementing the picking as described in the question, it is more efficient to shuffle the array and then print the elements.

```java
String[] colors = {"Black", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Mint", "Rose", "Purple" };
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(colors));
for (var color : colors) {
    System.out.println(color);
}
```

The algorithm described could be implemented with a `List`, though.

```java
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Black", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Mint", "Rose", "Purple"));
while (!colors.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(colors.remove(
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(colors.size())));
}
```

To print the remaining elements after removing instead:

```java
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Black", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Mint", "Rose", "Purple"));
while (colors.size() > 1) {
    colors.remove(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(colors.size()));
    System.out.println(colors);
}
```

Comment: This works well for outputting the initial list (it's a significant improvement on what I had, so thank you for that), but it only outputs the initial 8 and not the subsequent lists. So it'll shuffle the list and output that, but then it terminates, and if I run it again, it reshuffles the list of 8.

Comment: @JacobChristonsen What do you mean by subsequent lists? And you can use the code in the second part of my answer if you want the algorithm in your question implemented literally.

Comment: The original question was that I wanted it to output the list of 8, select one of those options, and then output a list of the remaining 7, etc all the way down to 1. As it runs, it will simply output the shuffled list of 8 every time. I've tried both of those code blocks, and they both work roughly the same, although the second works better, as the first trips under some circumstances.

Comment: @JacobChristonsen Can you please show the expected output then? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: It currently outputs a stacked list of 8. I've managed to consolidate it so it gives me [Black, Mint, Blue, White, Purple, Red, Green, Rose]. What I want is for it to then, either automatically or through a prompt, choose at random one of those colors, delete it, and then list the remaining options, such as [Black, Mint, White, Purple, Red, Green, Rose].

Comment: @JacobChristonsen So you want to remove an element and then print the entire remaining list? Here's an [example](https://tio.run/##ZVBBS8MwGL3vV3z0lIoGPE8L7iLCBrIJHsRDTD/XdGlSki@dU/bba9IWqewd8l6@98hLUotO3NTloe9V01pHUMcBD6Q0v1ouLmbSGhmcQ0PJbsOHVhKkFt7DRigDPwuImOaeBEXqrCqhiS7bkVNm//YOwu19PoUT1srT3egWIK22zsM9GDzCg3PiNNgFS8TtJ8tWWshDdg3Za6UIk9himWilw7B9dIgmiY0yNPjWD8ZzcK3GLM@Xf93HSmkENrZyr76R5VDA7fx@CVPAYWM7ZC@VQ1GurRR6K0xpGz79C8u5wS96iurfkfPKhN3JEzbcBuJtfDdpM@VnufNiXM99/ws) that does this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @JacobChristonsen Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I've created a list of 8 items, and I want Java to pick one at (psuedo)random and then remove it from the list. After that, I want it to repeat the process until it gets down to one item. ..."*

Shuffle the values in a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)*, then add to a *[Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html)* and use the *[poll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html#poll())* method.

```java
String[] color = {"Black", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Mint", "Rose", "Purple" };
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(color));
Collections.shuffle(list);
Deque<String> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(list);
while (!deque.isEmpty()) deque.poll();
```

Comment: This code runs, but it doesn't have an output. If I try to use System.out.println(color), it returns an LJava.lang string.  Edit: okay, I got it to output the colors by using list instead of color, but it outputs a shuffled list of 8 instead of picking and deleting.

Comment: @JacobChristonsen, the changes are not transitive, use the _Deque_.  If you wanted to print _color_, use the _[Arrays#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]))_ method.